# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'snd_aloop': No such device

Tags: audio, kernel-module, alsa, gentoo, jack

I'm trying to make a Jack-ALSA bridge on gentoo, but I cannot load the snd_aloop module.

Kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux MalfattiTux 4.6.7-rt-rt11 #1 SMP Thu Sep 22 14:54:42 BRT 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

snd_aloop compiled as a module:

```
$ cat /usr/src/linux-4.6.7-rt11/.config | grep ALOOP
CONFIG_SND_ALOOP=m
```

snd_aloop info:

```
$ sudo modinfo snd_aloop
filename:       /lib/modules/4.6.7-rt-rt11/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-aloop.ko
license:        GPL
description:    A loopback soundcard
author:         Jaroslav Kysela <perex@perex.cz>
depends:        snd-pcm
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.6.7-rt-rt11 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           index:Index value for loopback soundcard. (array of int)
parm:           id:ID string for loopback soundcard. (array of charp)
parm:           enable:Enable this loopback soundcard. (array of bool)
parm:           pcm_substreams:PCM substreams # (1-8) for loopback driver. (array of int)
parm:           pcm_notify:Break capture when PCM format/rate/channels changes. (array of int)
```

Settings for the snd_aloop module:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf | grep aloop
options snd-aloop id=Loopback index=0 pcm_substreams=2 enable=1
alias snd-card-0 snd-aloop
```

Audio devices:

```
$ sudo lspci | grep -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

$ sudo lspci -k -s 00:03.0
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

$ sudo lspci -k -s 00:1b.0
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

All looks ok. But then:

```
$ sudo modprobe snd_aloop
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'snd_aloop': No such device
```

I also tried compiling it not as a module, but included in the kernel. Then, I had loopback devices, but I had no control over them (like number of substreams, for example).

Is there any specific setting needed for this module to work on gentoo?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` option of a sound driver specifies the card number it should use.
However, this does not work if another driver is already loaded at the same index.

So you have to set matching `index` options on all drivers that are used (and might be used in the future, such as USB audio).

A better idea is to drop all `index` options, and to use the `slots` options of the `snd` module to specify that only a specific driver can use a specific index:

```
options snd slots=snd-aloop,snd-hda-intel,snd-hda-intel
```

or if the loopback driver should not be the first (default) one:

```
options snd slots=snd-hda-intel,snd-hda-intel,snd-aloop
```

Comment: That perfectly answered the question, thanks a lot! Just a minor thing, I placed the modules as in your first example, and the loopback devices are still the last cards. Any clue on why this order is not being followed?

Comment: Last in `/proc/asound/cards`? Maybe some forgotten `index` option.

Comment: Yes, the last both in `/proc/asound/cards` and `aplay -l`. No index in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf`... As a workaround, I added an `id=` option for each entry, now I'm using names instead of the index. Thanks again :)